# add a condition while inserting data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

Basicly I want to check if a specific data exists in the database before inserting data(im using native mongodb driver), so what I tried is using `collection.findOne()` to check if data exists, if the property of the attribute is null the `collection.insert()` performs.

Apparently my code is not working according the logic, please someone enlighten me!

some of my code:

```
exports.addUser = function(req, res) {
    var twitterId = req.body.provider;
    var userEmail = req.body.email;

    db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'email':userEmail }, function(err, item){

            if(item.email === null){

                collection.insert({
                    'email': userEmail,
                    'provider': {
                        'twitter': {
                            'id': twitterId
                        }
                    }
                }, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
                    } else {
                        console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
                        res.send(result[0]);
                    }
                });   

            }else{
                console.log("Email exits ");
            }
        });


    });
}
```

Comment: I think i have a clue, upsert might be the way to solve it...?

Comment: Right, what you want to do is a [`collection.update`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update) with the `upsert: true` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement is expecting `item.email` to be explicitly set to `null`. If `item.email` is not a property of `item`, that if statement will evaluate to `false`.

```
var foo = {bar:'baz'}
foo.bar // 'baz'
foo.notSet // undefined
foo.notSet === undefined // true
foo.notSet === null // false

// now if we set foo.notSet to undefined...
foo.notSet = null // undefined
foo.notSet === null // true
```

So, there are few options...

```
if (item.email) {} else {};
if ('email' in item) {} else {};
if (item.hasOwnProperty('email')) {} else {};
```

If you try and call a property that does not exist on the object itself, JS will check it's prototype, if it doesn't exist on the prototype anywhere, then it will return undefined.

The `in` operator will check to see if the left side operand is a property of the right side object.

Finally `Object.hasOwnProperty` will check for it's argument as a property on the object.

All that to say, `{upsert:true}` would probably be your best bet.